# Created Apache Alias But Getting 403 Error

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

I am having a folder outside of apache directory, let say /projects which is not in /var/www/html directory, now i want to creat an alias so that when i type localhost/projetcs it loads /projtect folder.

For this i had created an alias as follows -

```
Alias /projects "/home/rahul/Projects"

    <Directory "/home/rahul/Projects">
        Options +Indexes
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

but when i try to load localhost/projetcs it gives 403 error and on log reports it says

```
(13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:46784] AH00035: access to /projects denied (filesystem path '/home/rahul/Projects') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below, to give permission to folder -

```bash
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/rahul/Projects
cd /home/rahul/Projects/
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 0775 {} \;
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} \;
```

Then refresh the website page.